# Why doesn't VSphere show VMWare Tools as installed?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-server, opensuse

I just installed a fresh openSuSE 13.2 VM onto ESXi 6.  I did the VMware-install.pl process and it completes successfully, reporting as installed.  However, both our monitoring software (What's Up Gold) and VSphere itself report that VMWare-Tools is not installed.

I've rebooted, uninstalled, reinstalled, rebooted some more, etc.  Seems like perhaps I'm missing some secret setup trick, but I've installed this version of openSuSE, with VMWare-Tools, on previous versions of ESXi with no problems.  Other openSuSE VMs installed previously have survived the ESXi 5.5 to 6 upgrade intact (no VMWare Tools issues there).  Is there a change required for fresh openSuSE VMs in ESXi 6.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're supposed to use [open-vm-tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2073803) for that OS/hypervisor combination.

Comment: Well, my results are the same with open-vm-tools.  Installs, says it's running, but is not detected by VSphere.

Comment: Ended up doing a VMWare-Tools install process, but rebooting the server at the point in the script when it finishes uninstalling, but before it does the re-install (on the guess that maybe a regular uninstall was ineffective).  Then I installed Open-VM-Tools and enabled it as a service.  Was immediately recognized by WUG and VSphere.